# Jetpack Compose: "remember" inside if statement?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

What does Jetpack Compose do if you put a `remember` statement inside some conditional branch?

For example, take the following code:

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(repository: Repository?) {
    if (repository != null) {
        val myState by remember(repository) { repository.myFlow }.collectAsState()
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Suppose the first composition has some valid `repository` parameter, but then we have a recomposition with `repository = null`. The `remember` statement will not be called then; will the remembered value be cleared? (Otherwise this would be a memleak, would it not?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be lost. I believe so because what you are passing into `remember` as a parameter, is basically a `key`, and if the key changes, remember will be called again. However, since in your case, when the key changes, i.e., when the repository is null, the very block of remember will not be executed, so it will be just like the first time the composable was created. Nothing is remembered, and no data is stored because of no execution

Here's your confirmation: [image: screenshot of official docs]

Some reference,
[image: from State Docs]

Comment: Yes, one could argue that since remember is itself a Composable, all of its state will be lost once it leaves the composition. I was just a bit unsure because I don't think this is stated explicitly in the docs (I don't feel like your reference is very explicit about this either, is it?)

Comment: I pointed to your specific use case. You are passing a variable as a key. This is definite, that on change of the variable from non-null to null, the value definitely will be lost. That would explain the particular code you've mentioned in the question. If your question is more general, consider modifying it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, the new reference is more explicit. Still, it does not say exactly what happens when the composable that called "remember" stays in the composition but does not call "remember" anymore. But I am convinced now that the stored data will indeed be cleared.

Comment: I'm glad you are